# What effects can reveal demons?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

(Ignoring the miscellaneous supernatural detection abilities that might be in non-Demon related books, like Mage.)

> Whenever a demon is subjected to an effect that might reveal
>   her to be a supernatural being, she may attempt to “spoof” the
>   effect, fooling it into thinking she’s an ordinary human. A
>   demon cannot spoof in demonic form, for obvious reasons.
>   The demon does not have to be aware of the effect to spoof it;
>   spoofing happens reflexively. The demon does not necessarily
>   know where the incoming detection attempt is coming from.
>   Spoofing doesn’t affect any power or effect that doesn’t
>   explicitly detect whether a target is human or supernatural,
>   nor does it inhibit any effects other than that detection.

The thing is, there are only two effects in the whole book that seem to be able to detect supernatural beings/demons in particular: the Supernatural Merits **Aura Reading** and **Unseen Sense (God-Machine)**, which stigmatics and mortals can have.

There are several mentions of spoofing that imply there are other methods, but they don't explain further at all.

Like the Flagged Condition:

> **Flagged**
>   The God-Machine or one of its agents is suspicious of you.
>   It doesn’t know for sure that you’re a rogue angel, but it’s got
>   you marked as a potential problem. Attempts to spoof agents of
>   the God-Machine suffer a –3 penalty.
>   Resolution: Convince an agent of the God-Machine that
>   you’re an ordinary human without spoofing it.

And the Blown Condition:

> **Blown** (Persistent)
>   the
>   only way to lose it is to destroy the compromised cover. You
>   can’t spoof angels, God-Machine cultists, or anyone with the
>   Unseen Sense (God-Machine) Merit.

But I can't find a Numen that an angel could even have that would identify a supernatural being in the first place. The mention of "agents of the God-Machine" and "God-Machine cultists" could be mortals that have Aura Reading, but there doesn't seem to be anything an angel can ever do that could be spoofed.

What can an angel do that a demon can spoof?

Weirder is the **Behind the Curtain** Exploit description:

> Demons can use the Spoof ability when entering
>   Infrastructure and are well-advised to do so in this case.
>   Spoofing is described on p. 112. Successfully Spoofing adds two
>   dice to this Exploit’s roll.

Spoofing isn't something you can do of your own initiative, by definition it's always in reaction to something, but I can't find anything in the book that says there's something like an active effect of 'scan for demons' at every Infrastructure entrance.

Comment: Silver surfaces don't reveal true nature of things? What about indirect clues, like weaknesses?

Comment: No and no. There isn't even such a thing as a weakness that all demons share, and that wouldn't be a pure 'detection' effect.

Answer (score 1):

## The Spoofing is the Appearance of Being Human

In the case you describe, it's not that the demon has to evade an angel's demon sensing power, it's that any action on the demon is spoofed so that *the demon reacts in the same fashion as a human.* From the DtD core book:

> Whenever a demon is subjected to an effect that might reveal her to be a supernatural being, she may attempt to “spoof” the effect, fooling it into thinking she’s an ordinary human.

So if the angel tries any Numina or Influence on the demon then the demon responds as a normal person would, rather than revealing that they are not a human. This happens even if the demon does not know that any such ability is being used on them.

Comment: Except *"Spoofing doesn’t affect any power or effect that doesn’t explicitly detect whether a target is human or supernatural"*

Comment: This has been addressed in other questions here, e.g. can a demon be detected by a mage because they don't appear as a sleepwalker: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64337/do-demons-in-cover-generate-disbelief  Spoofing means (as I read it) that they automatically try to mimic morals in all of their responses to supernatural influences.